# No logro insertar datos por medio del formulario php

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

En mi siguiente formulario dentro de una pagina php trato de insertar un email y una contraseña dentro de la base de datos. Pero no me especifica el porque no se puedo realizar esa operacion y me sale el mensaje error " No resulto"

```
<div class="panel-login">
   <div class="header"><div class="user"><img src="IMG/icon.png" width=90 alt=""></div><span class="text">Iniciar sesión</span></div>
      <form method="POST" action="#">
         <input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="email" />
         <input type="password" name="contraseña" class="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="valider" value="Crear" />
         <center><u><a href="Index.php">Si ya tiene una cuenta, ingrese aqui</a><u/><center/>
      </form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
   {     
      if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['contraseña'])) 
      {
         $email=$_POST['email'];
         $contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

         $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
         mysql_select_db('usuario') or die("no se puede seleccionar base de datos");
         $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='".$email."'");
         $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

         if($numrows==0)
         {
            $sql="INSERT INTO login(email,contraseña) VALUES('$email','$contraseña')";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            if($result)
            {
               echo "email ingresado correctamente";
            } 
            else 
            {
               echo "no resulto";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Email ya registrado";
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
         echo "Llene todos los campos";
      }
   }?>
</div>
```

hay algo que deba agregar o borrar?

Comment: Prueba en los (*name* e *id*) tags html y campos de la BD evita usar la **ñ**; has los cambios pertinentes y prueba; te comento que **mysql_**  esta siendo retirado; mira respecto a **mysqli_** y realiza los cambios prudentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola buenas noches ya encontre donde esta tu error, al parecer se genera un conflicto utilizando la ñ:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$contrase\xc3\xb1a'
La solucion es cambiar la palabra contraseña por contrasena o otra palabra como pass, por lo general en el uso de variables y nombre de campos en la base datos no se recomienda el uso de la letra ñ, solo para mostrar los datos.

Por otro lado utilizas la funcion mysql_connect para conectarte y realizar tus consultas, el problema es que es una funcion que ya esta deprecada en PHP 7
http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php

Te recomiendo utilizar esta 
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Y por ultimo utilizando la ultima libreria y cambiando los nombres quedaria asi tu archivo

```
 <div class="panel-login">
 <div class="header"><div class="user"><img src="IMG/icon.png" width=90 alt=""></div><span class="text">Iniciar sesión</span></div>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
     <input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="email" />
     <input type="password" name="contrasena" class="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="valider" value="Crear" />
     <center><u><a href="Index.php">Si ya tiene una cuenta, ingrese aqui</a><u/><center/>
  </form>
```

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['contrasena'])) 
        {

```
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     $contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

     $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','usuario') or die(mysql_error());

     $query= $con->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='".$email."'");

     $numrows= $query->num_rows;

     if($numrows==0)
     {

         $sql="INSERT INTO login(email,contrasena) VALUES('$email','$contrasena')";

        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if($result)
        {
           echo "email ingresado correctamente";
        } 
        else 
        {
           echo "no resulto";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Email ya registrado";
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
     echo "Llene todos los campos";
  }
 }?>
```

Como veras el codigo es casi igual sin muchos cambios

saludos!